# PHP Replace a random word from a string and replace with variable

Tags: php

I know the title is similar to other questions but I cannot find what I'm looking for.

I have a variable, say:

```
$myVar = 'bottle';
```

And, then I have a string:

```
$myString = 'Hello this is my string';
```

I need some code to select a random word the `$myString` and replace it with `$myVar`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$myVar = "bottle";
$myString = 'Hello this is my string';

$words = explode(" ", $myString);
$words[rand(0, count($words)-1)] = $myVar;
echo join(" ", $words);
```

Answer (score 6):

Nothing like a good old-fashioned PHP race:

```
$myString = 'Hello this is my string';
$myVar = 'bottle';

$words = explode(' ', $myString);      // split the string into words    
$index = rand(0, count($words) - 1);   // select a random index    
$words[$index] = $myVar;               // replace the word at the random position
$myString = implode(' ', $words);      // merge the string back together from the words
```

You could also do this using regular expressions:

```
$idx = rand(0, str_word_count($myString) - 1);
$myString = preg_replace("/((?:\s*\w+){".$idx."})(?:\s*\w+)(.*)/", 
                         "\${1} $myVar\${2}", $myString);
```

This skips forward a random number of words and replaces the next word.

You can see this regex in action [here](http://regex101.com/r/gN8zT0). Changing the number inside the curly braces causes the first capture group to consume more words.

Answer (score 2):

You could just count the number of word separators (spaces in this case) and user `rand` to get random one of them, then just get the content of that word by `strpos` with `rand` value offset (third parameter) or just explode the string to array (by space) and then `implode` again (with space again) to string after replacing random word.

Answer (score 2):

It is what you need:

```
$myVar = 'bottle';
$myString = 'Hello this is my string';
$myStringArray = explode(' ', $myString);

$rand = mt_rand(0, count($myStringArray)-1);
$myStringArray[$rand] = $myVar;

$myNewString = implode(' ', $myStringArray);
```

Answer (score 2):

Well how about this:

```
$words = explode(' ', $myString );
$wordToChange = rand(0, count($words)-1);
$words[$wordToChange] = $myVar;
$final = implode(' ', $words)
```

Comment: You explode the wrong var. $myVar is the replacement